# Is it possible to get analyzers to understand Jetbrains NotNull-attributes or equivalent?

Tags: c#, resharper, roslyn-code-analysis, c#-7.0

I've been using Jetbrains attribute [NotNull](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html) for reference arguments in methods to have ReSharper trust these in regards to not being null, while instead enforcing me to make sure that what I send into a NotNull-argument is checked on the calling side.

Example of ReSharper static analysis:
[image]

Now I'm starting to use [analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2019), these don't care about the ReSharper attributes and will trigger the CA1062 warning in the method body regardless of whether I decorate the arguments with `NotNull` or not.

[image]

In many cases I prefer static code analysis instead of using null-checking and throwing ArgumentNull-exceptions runtime. ReSharper is still warning me about function calls with NotNull-arguments, but I'd like to also have the analyzers trust arguments within a method body marked with this attribute.

Comment: Could you please share the code samples?

Answer (score 0):

Roslyn analyzers are static code analyzers. They can't give you any guarantees about the run-time behavior of the code.

[C# 8.0's nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) tries to make educated guesses about the nullability of references.

If may want to look at Fody or PostSharp to add annotations to automate these run-time checks.

Comment: I'm also talking about static code analysis, I've updated my question.

Comment: Even when using C# 8.0 it is recommended to have all null checks because there is no guarantee that the caller will not send null values.